# Capitalize every word in Edit text while typing

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to capitilze every word in edit text while typing.

My XML:-

```
<com.project.edittext.AutoFitEditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                style="@style/scan_text_fields_white_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:digits="@string/validation_accept_all_except_special_char"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapWords"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                />
```

Now I am using

```
mName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
```

**But problem is it is not working in some device. Ex LG tablet. So I decided to do this programatically.**

So I am using following codes.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                   
                String mNameStr=s.toString();
                String finalStr="";
                if(!mNameStr.equals("")) {
                    String[] strArray = mNameStr.split("[\\s']");
                    if (strArray.length > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
                            finalStr+=capitalize(strArray[i]);
                        }
                        Logger.d("finalStr==> ", finalStr);
                    }
                }
                mName.setText(finalStr.toString());
            }



private String capitalize(final String line) {
        return Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) + line.substring(1);
    }
```

Here my app getting crash. I found the problem while debugging. Problem is the onTextChanged is not getting stopped. So that it execute continuously. Anyone help me to resolve my problem. I want to capitalize every word. Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: android:inputType="textCapWords"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize every letter in an Android EditText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705776/how-to-capitalize-every-letter-in-an-android-edittext)

Comment: if its crashing then attach the logcat for the exception thrown

Comment: I would suggest you to use `split("\\s+")` instead. Also, can you post your logcat.

Comment: Crash issue is because of continuously executing. If I remove `mName.setText(finalStr)` it is working fine. Because if I do setText `onTextChanged` calling again. So it calling again and again.

Comment: Finally I decided to do it programatically. Because I think it is not possible for this device. So please help me to do this by programatically.

Comment: A Quick optimization would be only to captilize the sentence only if the last entered letter is after a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code freezes is that the `onChangeListener` is triggered as soon as you `setText`.

You'll have to find a way to stop trigering if the text is the same.

For this you can use a temp string to store the prev value and compare each time the event triggers. This will keep the flow to be consistent and not looping.

`String prevString = "";`

---

In `afterTextChanged`

```
String mNameStr = s.toString();
String finalStr = "";
if (!mNameStr.equals("")) {
 String[] strArray = mNameStr.split("[\\s']");
 if (strArray.length > 0) {
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < strArray.length - 1; i++) {
   finalStr += capitalize(strArray[i]) + " ";
  }
  finalStr += capitalize(strArray[i]);
  Log.d("finalStr==> ", finalStr);
 }
}
if (!finalStr.equals(prevString)) {
 prevString = finalStr;
 editText.setText(finalStr.toString());
 editText.setSelection(finalStr.length());
}
```

---

An optimization to your code is to only capitalize the sentence if the last entered letter is after a space. You can see it implemented here.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String string = s.toString();
            Log.d("STRING", string + " " + prevString);
            if (string.equals(prevString)) {
                return;
            } else if (string.length() == 0)
                return;
            // 1st character
            else if (string.length() == 1) {
                prevString = string.toUpperCase();
                editText.setText(string.toUpperCase());
                editText.setSelection(string.length());
            }
            // if the last entered character is after a space 
            else if (string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(string.length() - 2) == ' ') {
                string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1) + Character.toUpperCase(string.charAt(string.length() - 1));
                prevString = string;
                editText.setText(string);
                editText.setSelection(string.length());
            }
        }
    });
```

However, there is a down-side to the above method. This will not consider the case where in you change the cursor position and enter text.

*PS: you can use `getSelectionEnd()` method and enhance the above method*

Comment: I think it will work. I will check and let you know @Uma Kanth..!!

Comment: Thank you Uma Kanth.. :-) It working FINE..!! Thanks AGAIN..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one of the following (in your .xml file), depending on what you need...

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"

android:inputType="textCapSentences"

android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

This is deprecated so don't use this `android:capitalize="characters"`

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your xml design

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords" />
```

Reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808705/first-letter-capitalization-for-edittext)

**EDIT**

If not working then try this

```
android:capitalize="characters"
```

to edit text in xml.

Reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386291/how-to-enforce-edittext-to-start-text-in-capital-letter)

Comment: I tried this. It is not working in particular devices. I am using LG tablet. It is not working in this tablet.

Comment: No luck :-( . I will add my XML also.

Comment: android:capitalize="characters" is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Add the following in the `<EditText ../>` in XML:

```
android:textAllCaps="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`afterTextChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) event,you should try to use that method when your input has been temporary finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Kotlin code to make every later of word in EditText to capital. It will change first later to capital while typing.

```
 private fun handleFirstLatterCap() {
        var prevString = ""
        edittext.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                var str = s.toString()
                if (str == prevString) {
                    return
                } else if (str.isEmpty()) return else if (str.length == 1) {
                    prevString = str.toUpperCase()
                    edittext.setText(str.toUpperCase())
                    edittext.setSelection(str.length)
                } else if (str.isNotEmpty() && str[str.length - 2] == ' ') {
                    str = str.substring(
                        0,
                        str.length - 1
                    ) + Character.toUpperCase(str[str.length - 1])
                    prevString = str
                    edittext.setText(str)
                    edittext.setSelection(str.length)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```